# Cypher match any node connected to a node filtered by last relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j graph looking like this:

```
(AdminUser) - [is_admin] -> (Tenat) - [can_edit,can_read] -> (Resource)

(RegularUser) - [can_edit] -> (Resource)

(RegularUser2) - [can_read] -> (Resource)
```

This a simplified version, so I want to get all Resource that a given user is connected on any path, but such that last relationship before Resource node is 'can_edit'

I would try something like

```
match(u:User{id:'regular'}) // I'd like to insert user id here

-[*]->(r:Resource)  // here not sure how to limit last relation as can_edit
```

In the example above, I'd like to get Resource when if I insert either AdminUser or RegularUser id, but not RegularUser2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something simple like:

```
match(u:User{id:'regular'})-[*0..]->()-[:can_edit]->(r:Resource)
```

This will make sure the the last relationship before the Resource is [:can_edit]

Comment: Yes, I also had that idea, and i works in most cases. However, it does not work if user is directly related to Resource, as it assumes at least one node in between. Now I am not sure if I can use somehow make [*]-() part optional, or maybe do some kind of or operator.. e.g. ((user)-[*]->()-[:can_edit]->(r:Resource)) or ((user)-[:can_edit]->(r:Resource))

Comment: So I found the way to make part of the path optional, using Zero length paths. I needed to also length to wildcard relationship [*0..]
So final query would be: `match(u:User{id:'regular'})-[*0..]->()-[:can_edit]->(r:Resource)  `

Comment: Updated according to your correct comment